# I am getting unexpected end of json input when requesting json file in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http');

const request = http.get('http://localhost:90/rentflig/ajaxfetchproperties.php', response => {

  console.log(response.statusCode);

  let body = "";

  response.on('data', data => {
    body += body.toString();
  });
  response.on('end', () => {

    var getData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(getDate.LocationName);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you where pretty close but there some missing pieces in your code

```
let body = [];
response.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
  const json = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean `data.toString()`:

```
response.on('data', data => {
  body += data.toString();
});
```